# Jquery validation to force lowercase and symbols

Tags: jquery, regex, validation

I have succeeded at failing.  I am trying to allow lowercase characters and symbols.  I am not very good at regex so feel free to laugh

```
$.validator.addMethod('lowercasesymbols', function(value) {
    return value.match(/^[a-z-"?=.*[!@# $%&\/=?_.,:;\\-]"]+$/);
}, 'You must use only lowercase letters and symbols in your entry');
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: I can't figure out what your regexp is doing. Why do you have multiple copies of the same character inside the `[...]` character class? You have `?`, `=`, `.` twice.

Comment: The reason it's allowing other characters is because of `.*`. This matches anything.

Comment: return value.match(/^[a-z-"?=.*[!@# $%&\/=?_.,:;\\-]"]+$/);  I pasted the old one.  I am simply trying to restrict numbers and capital letters.

Comment: try using `/^[a-z!@# $%^\/=?_.,:;\\-]+$/`. What's the deal with the extra `[]` around that anyway?

Comment: @DouglasCottrell Edit your question if you pasted it wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like you said in the comments, "I am simply trying to restrict numbers and capital letters."

To do that, simply make a test for that:

```
$.validator.addMethod('lowercasesymbols', function(value) {
    return value.match(/^[^A-Z0-9]+$/);
}, 'You must use only lowercase letters and symbols in your entry');
```

That way, you're matching anything that is *not* A-Z or 0-9. If it reaches the end that way, your string doesn't contain either of those things.

This way you will also allow any greek letters (including uppercase), accented letters (incl uppercase), etc. so this may not be exactly what you want. It is what you should use if you're *just* trying to restrict uppercase letters and numbers though.

For allowing just the symbols you mentioned, you still need to escape your square brackets (`\[` and `\]`), which was causing problems. Also, you've got multiple of the same characters in your range, which I've removed. Finally, you should *always* keep your dash at the end of the range, otherwise it'll match as if it's a range from the character before, to the character after. In your case, it's trying to match characters `\` to `]`, which won't work. This is the result of my cleanup:

```
$.validator.addMethod('lowercasesymbols', function(value) {
    return value.match(/^[a-z\[!@# $%&*\/?=_.,:;\\\]"-]+$/);
}, 'You must use only lowercase letters and symbols in your entry');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$.validator.addMethod('mypassword2', function(value, element) {
    
   return this.optional(element) || value.match(/[a-z]/);

},"Password must contain at least  one lowercase character");
```